# ESRI Web AppBuilder - custom attribute - only show fields that contain values

Tags: arcmap, web-mapping, attribute-table, popup, arcgis-web-appbuilder

Is there a way to only show fields that have a value, i.e. are not NULL, in the Web AppBuilder Web Map pop-up? If this can't be done in the Web Map can it be done in the mxd attribute table?

I have a service that contains a layer with many fields but some features in the layer may not have data in all fields. To increase the visual and usability of the viewer I would like to only show fields that have a value for each feature identified on.

Comment: Hey - are you using the development version of [WebAppBuilder](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/)? or the [Templated Version](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/). and how is the data created - are you making it in your mxd and then publishing to a server? or are you creating it on arcgis online and pulling it into webapp builder using a map on arcgis online?

Comment: Hi @MDHald, I'm using templated version. Yes I create services via mxd and publish to server.

Comment: In this case - if you apply a [definition query](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002z000000) to the data prior to sending it to the server i.e. MAPDATA IS NOT NULL. the query will carry through to the service.